Definition of automorphism groups
Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over some field.
Then, we want to define the automorphism groups $\operatorname{Aut}(V)$ constructed by all linear automorphisms between $V$.
Now, which is the usual definition of group strucuture, $f\cdot g:=f\circ g$ or $f\cdot g:=g\circ f$ for $f,g\in \operatorname{Aut}(V)$ ?
I consider $f\cdot g:=f\circ g$ is good since $\operatorname{GL}(n)$ is defined by $A\cdot B=A\circ B$.

The usual definition is $f \cdot g = f \circ g$. This way the canonical action of $\text{Aut}(V)$ on $V$, $g \cdot v = g(v)$, is actually a group action. If you do it the other way around, you do get an isomorphic group, but the above will not be an action, instead will be an anti-action.

This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Please notice that comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, I suggest to post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list. @DavidGao
